# How can I fuzzy match variables on names with same dates?

Tags: r, matching, string-matching, fuzzyjoin

I want to match two datasets. The names have different writings, so I would fuzzy match them, but the names have multiple entries of different months. How can I set up the matching so it matches the entries with the same months?

E.g

```
Data set 1 : Joe Doe / Jan/19, Joe Doe / June/17,
Data set 2 : Joe F. Doe / June 17, Joe F. Doe /Jan/19
```

-> match

```
Joe Doe / Joe F Doe / Jan/19
Joe Doe / Joe D Doe / June/17
```

Comment: Christian, welcome to SO! Please read how to make a *reproducible question*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Also: do a search on fuzzy matching in SO.